# how to automate hadoop services

Tags: hadoop

I would like to automate Hadoop,Hbase,hive,zookeeper etc services,whenever service is stopped or system shutdown then automatically restart without manual checking.Is it possible using supervisord(sudo supervisorctl command).Already i am using this one for hive and zookeeper.can i use same for hadoop and hbase services also or any other way is there.
I have to use these commands,

```
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-yarn.sh
/usr/local/hbase/bin/start-hbase.sh
```

is it better option or any other way is better than this...........

Comment: anybody have any idea please share me........

Comment: have you been able to automate them any help

Comment: No I am not able to do.If you have any idea about it,please help me.